# Programfault when dereferencing a 64bit int on due

Tags: arduino-due, pointer

I am running into a strange behaviour with my code. The following works without problems on an Arduino Nano but it seems to crash on a DUE

```
void putData64(byte* packet, int pos, uint64_t data)
{
    uint64_t* h= (uint64_t*) (packet+pos+2);
    *h= data;
}
```

the problematic line seems to be the second one (*h= data) as commenting it out lets the program run without problems.

Similar, the following lines cause a problem on a DUE but run fine on a Nano:

```
char* data;
// ... data is filled with something
uint64_t* t= (uint64_t*) (data+1);
uint64_t test= *t;
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Probably a memory alignment problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to use bytes and byte pointers, that is okay. If you want to use 64-bit and pointers to it, that is also okay. But you have mixed the two. Why would you want to point halfway to a 64-bit value. I suggest to start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with Majenko's comment: it's probably a memory alignment
problem. I don't know the specifics of the Due, but when you access
memory in chunks of 32 bit data words on a 32 bit CPU, it can
happen that the architecture requires the data words to be aligned to
32 bit (i.e. 4 byte) boundaries. This means that the address
of an `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` should be a multiple of 4. Maybe
even 8 for a `uint64_t`, you will have to check.

The only solution to this issue is to fill the packet *byte by byte*:

```c++
void putData64(byte* packet, int pos, uint64_t data)
{
    union {
        uint64_t integer;
        byte bytes[8];
    } h = { .integer = data };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        packet[pos+2+i] = h.bytes[i];
    }
}
```

Note that the AVR (in the Nano) is an 8 bit architecture with no
alignment constraints whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the fact of 8bit vs 32bit. I haven't tried your code but it seems right. What did the trick for me in the end was the following:

    void putData64(byte* packet, int pos, uint64_t data)
    {
        uint32_t* out= (uint32_t*) (packet+pos+2);
        uint32_t* in=  (uint32_t*) data;
        *(out++)= *(in++);
        *(out++)= *(in++);
    }

Comment: @user2912328: You mean `in = (uint32_t*) &data`? Note that, although this could work, it is quite fragile. Unless you can prove that `packet+pos+2` is _always_ a multiple of 4, there is a risk that `out` ends up being an incorrectly aligned (and thus invalid) pointer. If you have no guarantees on the alignment of `packet+pos+2`, the only valid solution is to copy the data byte by byte.

Comment: yes you are right about both points. Missing & and multiple of 4